# How to determine the best cut-off of measurement numbers for diagnostic decision?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, biostatistics, diagnostic

I am currently doing a research on determining a cut-off of a ECG signal's number of 12 patients with their diseased/normal label that is produced by classifier for diagnostic decision purpose. However, I am struggling to find a statistical test(s) to justify whether the cut-off is significant or not.

Here is how my data look like:

| Patient | Diagnosis Label | Threshold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Diseased | 90% of total signals assigned as Diseased |
| 2 | Normal | 95% of total signals assigned as Normal |
| 3 | Normal | 89% of total signals assigned as Normal |
| 3 | Normal | 91% of total signals assigned as Normal |
| ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 12 | Diseased | 88% of total signals assigned as Diseased |
|  | **Mean** | **91% of total signals assigned correctly** |

My objective is to decide whether the last row bolded on the above table is significant with a confidence of interval value.

I was trying to do a t-test, but, to the best of my knowledge, the test compares the means of two distribution, or test whether the hypothetical mean is equal, less, or more than an actual mean. The p-value of t-test represents the significance of those results.

I feels that the t-test is not fit for my research, because I think the t-test only justifies that two data set's mean is different, not judges whether the samples mean is representative for population mean.

Could you please suggests the fitter tests for my case?

Really thanks!